# WordPress site works while logged in to the site backend, breaks when not logged in

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Our site was working properly for a month or so and all of a sudden it won't work unless you are logged into the site backend [/wp-admin]. You can see the issue here - https://hema-filler.com/.

While not logged in, it strips off the domain name from the CSS/Image/JavaScript requests and you can see that in the screenshot -
[image: Domain name gets stripped off]

I'm only administering this site and not the developer. If you came across this kind of an issue before or if you know why this is happening, please post back.

This site is in Azure/Linux, on the latest WordPress version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the errors, your domain name is missing from the URL of the requests to the static content, which is why it is not loading properly. Please check your siteurl and homeurl inside your wp_options table in your database. If the issue still persists, then I would recommend checking with your hosting provider's support team. If they lack support, then I would recommend switching to managed WordPress hosting.